# How to get json return from servlet in javascript function in jsp?

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets

I wrote a jsp which request to the servlet and return a json to my jsp ,my problem is that I want to iterate on json and show it in my page ,but I do not know how to get my json in my javascript function .
I do not want to use jquery ui an ajax .
I want to write it in pure javascript and jsp .
tnx for ur help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9645647/return-json-from-servlet

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154845/returning-json-response-from-servlet-to-javascript-jsp-page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are already holding the JSON somewhere within your JSP, this examples shows how to access JSP content from a javascript function: [JSP/JavaScript-Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803906/jsp-variable-accssing-in-javascript). If my assumption is wrong, you maybe want to post your code for further suggestions.

Comment: I know the best way is using ajax but I was told to do this without using ajax !!

Comment: Assuming you are already holding the JSON somewhere within your JSP, this examples shows how to access JSP content from a javascript function: [JSP/JavaScript-Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803906/jsp-variable-accssing-in-javascript). If my assumption is wrong, you maybe want to post your code for further suggestions.

Comment: Just changed the content of my answer, to the content of the comment. You may want to mark it as correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this,

```
var json = xmlHTTPRequest.responseText,
obj = JSON.parse(json);
alert(objJSON.result);
alert(objJSON.count);
```

Comment: xmlHttpRequest is xhr and ajax ,I don't want to use ajax !