# Dynamic Ajax ComboBox Jsp/Servlet

Tags: ajax, jsp, combobox

I am new to Ajax and I am having trouble thinking how to do this, I will describe it in brief.

I have 2 combo boxes:

1) First combo box contain a list of classrooms.

2) When you choose an item in the first combo box (a classroom for example).

3) The second combo box will then have a list of student inside the classroom that the first combo box choose without reloading the page.

Is it possible for Ajax to do this in Jsp/Servlet?.

Comment: That's of course possible with JSP/Servlets and we *could* provide you with a working example. But that would do you a disfavour. You *need to* to gain knowledge on your own to carry on. To my taste, [coreservlets.com](http://coreservlets.com/) is a great starting point.

Comment: if you have an example please show me...i will gain knowledge as i do it, i believe :)..

Answer (score 0):

To start with.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getStudents()(){
    var classVal = $("#class").value();
    var url = "getDataServlet";
    $.ajax({
            url : url, // Pass you Servlet Mapping / JSP Url
            data : {
                classId : classVal
            }, // This will be passed as parameter to server (JSP/Servlet)
            dataType : 'json',
            success : function(response) {
                alert('Success');
                // perform tasks for success 
               // fill combo with json data received from server
            },
            error : function(request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(request.status + ', Error: ' + request.statusText);
                 // perform tasks for error 
            }
        });
}
</script>
<title>JQuery Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <select name="class" id="class" onchange="getStudents();">
        <option value='class1'>Class One</option>
        <option value='class2'>Class Two</option>
    </select>

    <select name="student" id="student"></select>

</body>
</html>
```

Create a Servlet with mapping Then, There are plenty of questions on [How to Return Json response from Servlet ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9645647/return-json-from-servlet).