# HTML content in JSON object

Tags: java, html, json, internet-explorer

When I try to send HTML content in JSON object as a response from servlet, then IE 10 does not receive HTML content with tags. 
Response type is `application/json`

Java:

```java
String summaryRptHTML = sum.generateSummaryTable(summary, false);
jSonObj.put("hasError", false); 
jSonObj.put("message", "File Proceesed"); 
jSonObj.put("summary", summaryRptHTML );
```

JavaScript :

```
Client: "ProcessFileServlet", 
function(responseJSON) { 
  System.hideLoadingScreen(""); 
  responseJSON = eval(responseJSON); 
  responseJSON.summary; // its nothing 
}
```

Comment: Please share some code. That make sense....

Comment: String summaryRptHTML = sum.generateSummaryTable(summary, false);
   jSonObj.put("hasError", false);
   jSonObj.put("message", "File Proceesed");
   jSonObj.put("summary", summaryRptHTML );

Client: 
"ProcessFileServlet", function(responseJSON) {
     System.hideLoadingScreen("");
     responseJSON = eval(responseJSON);
responseJSON.summary; // its nothing

}

Answer (score 0):

Do you json_encode your html you are sending and using a JSON decoder on the Java side?

```
json_encode($your_html)
```

Comment: Hello Ronal,
same code is working for FF, chrome and Opera but I.E is generation apart from these browsers.
when i set response type to text/html then IE fetch html data without html tags.
and when i set response type to application/json then IE do not get any HTML content.

Comment: Maybe this answer could help you:
[return-json-from-servlet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9645647/return-json-from-servlet)

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved! :)
Server Side:
use resonse type text/plain

Client Side:
Use EVAL() function on jsonobj
responseJSON = EVAL(responseJSON);