# How to get attribute in angular side after sending a response from server side (servlet)

Tags: angular, http, servlets, request

```
@WebServlet("/findPerson")
public class FindPerson extends HttpServlet {
    // ... doGet implementation

    @Override
    protected void doPost( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response )
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        // data to send to the client
        String name = "John White";
        int age = 54;



        // Adding attributes to the request
        request.setAttribute( "personName", name );
        request.setAttribute( "personAge", age );

        }
    }
}
```

How do I get the value of these attributes "personName" and "personAge" in angular after calling

```
return  this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/findPerson',"");
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.http.post()` returns an observable. You need to subscribe to it to obtain the response

Service

```js
findPerson(): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/findPerson',"");
}
```

Component

```js
name: any;
age: any;

this.someService.findPerson().subscribe(
  res => {
    this.name = res['personName'];
    this.age = res['personAge'];
    console.log(this.name); // <-- correct
    console.log(this.age); // <-- correct
  },
  error => {
    // always good practice to handle HTTP errors
  }

  console.log(this.name); // <-- wrong - would print `undefined`
  console.log(this.age); // <-- wrong - would print `undefined`
);
```

Most important thing to note is that the call is asynchronous. So any statements that directly depend on the response *should* be inside the subscription. Or in other words, you need to subscribe where the response is required.

You could learn more about asynchronous data [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/6513921).

Comment: [Error] ERROR – TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'res['status']') — login.component.ts:55
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'res['status']') — login.component.ts:55(anonymous function) — login.component.ts:55__tryOrUnsub — ....

Comment: @Ashim: It appears the server isn't sending anything back. I'm not familiar with HttpServlet, but I don't see something being returned. Eg. I don't see the MIME type of the response. Please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9645647/6513921) on how to return an object in JSON from Servlet.